# Duane "Dog" Chapman, what is the word for the part in quotes between forename and surname?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, names

Apologies if this has been asked before, I found it quite difficult to phrase what I meant!

As the question title states:

Duane **"Dog"** Chapman.

What is the correct word to describe the part that is intentionally in quotes?

e.g:

- Jimmy "The Greek" Smith.
- Anthony "The Executioner" Thomas.

Comment: You're not talking about *alias*, or AKA (also known as) are you?

Comment: There was once the parody Charlie "Charles" Charles in a comedy programme whose name I've forgotten.

Comment: Charles "Charlie" Charles was in the Harry Enfield Television Program  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4CXY6TVBMc

Comment: It's a nicknomen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While tchrist’s answer quite accurately describes in brief what distinguishes various types of nicknames, the specific question here seems to be whether there is a term for the practice of listing a nickname adjacent to or wedged inside a person’s full name. The very brief and short answer is that there is no such term in common use. At least, I had never heard this practice described with a term before researching a bit here.

A bit of research indicates, however, that, although the original definition of the term was somewhat different and relevant only to Latin names in the Roman Empire, this comes under the category of ***agnomina***. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnomen) notes most specifically of agnomina that:

> An *agnomen* is not a pseudonym, but a real name; agnomina are *additions* to, not *substitutions* for, an individual’s full name. Parallel examples of agnomina from later times are epithets like Thomas Jonathan ‘Stonewall’ Jackson (though he is known more often by his agnomen than his first name) or popular nicknames like ‘Iron’ Mike Tyson or Michael ‘Air’ Jordan.

On the other hand, the [OED definition](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4067) defines *agnomen* as:

> A name used *instead of or in addition to* an original or usual name; an agname, a byname; […] [Emphasis mine]

– which would indicate that this distinction is not universal, and that regular nicknames that *replace* a part of someone’s name are also sometimes called agnomina. (Compare how Michael Jordan is also sometimes simply referred to as *‘Air’ Jordan*, where the nickname basically does take over the function of the first name, becoming a kind of pseudonym.)

The original definition of an *agnomen* in a Latin name is (as [defined by ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agnomen)):

> A fourth name occasionally given as an honour to an ancient Roman citizen

Quoting Marius Victorinus, the Wikipedia page tells us that this fourth name –

> *[…] extrinsecus venit, et venit tribus modis, aut ex animo aut ex corpore aut ex fortuna: ex animo, sicut Superbus et Pius, ex corpore, sicut Crassus et Pulcher, ex fortuna, sicut Africanus et Creticus*
>
> ([…] comes from outside, and in three styles, from personality or physique or achievements: From personality, such as *Superbus* [‘Haughty’] and *Pius* [displaying the Roman syndrome of virtues including honesty, reverence to the gods, devotion to family and state, etc.], from physique, such as *Crassus* [‘Fatty’] and *Pulcher* [‘Handsome’], or from achievements, such as *Africanus* and *Creticus* [from their victories in Africa and on Crete])

(The last type is known as a *victory title*.)

So while the term started out as referring to an extra honorary name given sometimes to certain Roman citizens, it is quite understandable from its description that it would later be applied to our current convention of including various types of nicknames inside (or at least somehow as part of) a person’s full reported name.

Comment: I think the cops called them *aliases*.  It might be interesting to try to tease out the distinction in naming styles between *Leif Erikson* and his father *Erik the Red*, but that may be too far removed from the OP. I wonder if this is actually a variable-naming question in disguise.

Comment: @tchrist An alias to me is more likely to be a pseudonym, i.e., an entirely different name under which someone is known. The many different names assumed by James Bourne, for example, would be stereotypical _aliases_, but while I certainly have no trouble with someone talking about Ma Barker as Arizona Donnie Barker’s alias, it’s not the first sense of _alias_ that pops into my head. And a term for the specific practice of adding a nickname in inverted commas _as part of a full reported name_ is not any sense of _alias_ that would come to me. _Alias_ to me is the name, not the practice.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderfully researched answer.  For what it is worth, I am programming a game that creates names, and for some - I wanted a... a... *something*..  that would hint to the player that the person in question had some sort of trait.  I may not be the first programmer to create a property called "Agnomina", but it sure does sound sexy. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice You probably want *agnomen*, presuming that each character shall have only one. *Agnomina* is the plural of *agnomen*.

Comment: @Superbest You could hardly have chosen a worse candidate in all of ELU for such an unfound accusation. I can think of perhaps two others at most, and probably not even them. There is no cause for such extreme sarcasm, whether misplaced or not. And in this case, I quite assure you that it is entirely misplaced. I urge you to edit or remove your unkindness before the ravens gather.

Comment: @Superbest, my question was not about whether or not he deserves the nickname/Agnomen, but what the word actually *is*.  Hence also in my question, I used 2 made up ones.  Whatever your personal feelings towards Duane Chapman are, it was used as an example.  If we get hung up on the details of an example as you have, we'd never get anywhere!

Comment: @Moo-Juice That is my point, the way in which he uses his nickname, and the nature of the word used as a nickname, appears to be different from the way in which "agnomen" is used, or the nature of words used as agnomens. I am unconvinced that applying it to your examples may be seen as pretentious.

Answer (score 10):

The second set are ***epithets*** or ***sobriquets***, because they are things other people call them, more like titles in that they can have separate words and even articles.  You would not use a term with an article vocatively; that is, as a form of direct address.

On the other hand, a ***nickname*** is usually a short name that you do use to address that person with, such as in *Robert Francis “Bobby” Kennedy* or in *Francis “Frank” Scott Key*.  If your fellow there is actually addressed as *Dog* to his face, as in, “Tell me, Dog, how was breakfast today?”, then it is more of nickname than a mere sobriquet.

If your pal James Smith walks in the room, you might say, “Hey Jimmy, wanna join us for breakfast?” You would not say, “Hey (*The) Greek, wanna join us for breakfast?”

Another related but learnèd word is ***hypocorism***.  These are little names derived directly from the original, “full” name that are often used on children and intimate, and which may remain with the bearer as they age. This term might be more appropriate in some contexts for those little ***pet names*** we call people by instead of their longer names, like *Billy* for *William*, *Peggy* for *Margaret*, or *Paco* for *Francis*.

On the other hand, if her lover always calls *Samantha* by the name of *Kitten*, that is more clearly a *pet name*.

Other related words include ***bynames***, ***monikers***, and ***cognomina***.

Based on followup comments, it is possible that the best word for the OP here is an ***alias*** or an ***assumed name***.  Those may have criminal overtones, however.

In many cases, no precise distinction can be drawn in the sand demarcating the domain of one of these words from those of the others. They are also used in different registers, since some are French, Greek, or Latin, while others are native English words.  Without knowing the fuller context, it may not be possible to favor one or the others.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer, thanks...  Unless I am mistaken though, I'm looking for the word that describes the fact you placed said "nickname" in between the forename and surname, as you might find at the end of an email signature.  Apologies if I was misleading.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Me, I don’t actually ever find something in quotes between the first name and the last name in an email signature. I suppose you could call it an ***alias*** or ***alternate name***.

Comment: An alias is a name assumed instead of the actual name with the intention to conceal identity (whether to avoid recognition, or avoid connotations of a given name). Dog is not used in place of his name, but alongside it. Police officers may refer to it as an alias, because for reasons pertaining to police work they use "alias" to mean "whatever name the person may readily be identified by". I am extremely skeptical that "Dog" is a hypocorism or pet name, as well.

Comment: Nor does alias have criminal overtones like you claim, except in the superficial sense. There is a very established tradition for perfectly legitimate works of literature being published under an alias (which is as often called such as the synonym in that context, "pen name"), for reasons having nothing to do with criminality.

Comment: @Superbest I was really trying to avoid going into *noms de plume et de guerre*. There are many reasons for assumed named used to conceal one’s legal birth name, of which not a few are sketchy ones.

Comment: @tchrist Well, to be sure, all three of OP's examples sound like street names. Anyhow, I don't think it makes sense to say that "Dog" is his alias, except in professional parlance with your fellow law enforcement workers.

Answer (score 0):

"Nickname". It's not an "epithet" which is usually descriptive: e.g. Charles the Bald.

Comment: Although I concede it is a nickname, I seem to remember there being a specific word for when it is used, in quotes, between forename and surname (but will happily be corrected!)